# sequelize-typescript Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'escape' of undefined"

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

I'm keep trying to connect my mysql db with sequelize-typescript, there are bunch of errors which i cannot find reason.

The error occur when "Sync()" Function has invoked. The function drop well, but error has show up when create tables.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/main.ts run`
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Comments`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Feeds`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'escape' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\data-types.js:122:55
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ENUM.toSql (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\data-types.js:122:34)
    at ARRAY.toSql (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js:775:25)
    at ARRAY.toString (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js:17:17)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributeToSQL (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:364:44)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributesToSQL (C:\Users\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:434:45)
    at MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:222:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Function.sync (C:\Users\Hyuntae\projects\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1300:5)
```

And this is my code.

```
import Logger from './logger';
import { sequelize } from './sequelize';

export default async ({ expressApp }) => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  Logger.info('Express loaded');
};
```

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import config from '../config';
import { User } from '../models/User';
import { Feed } from '../models/Feed';
import { Comment } from '../models/Comment';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mysql',
  database: config.database,
  username: config.databaseUsername,
  password: config.databasePassword,
  host: config.databaseHost,
  port: config.databasePort,
  storage: ':memory',
  models: [User, Feed, Comment],
  repositoryMode: true,
});
```

Could someone advice me which code was wrong?

I don't have any Idea :(

Comment: add your model defination..

Comment: @IleshPatel Thx for advice. I just thought, It happen because of above code... You gave me hint. That's model error.. :(